# Generating a magic square

Tags: c, magic-square

This is a magic square problem, the size of the magic square n should be inputed as a command line argument. n has to be a odd number.
 [The expected output should be like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkvQF.png) My problem is that when I try to execute the code, 
[it generates a bunch of 0s.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZozl.png)

I am a C beginner and I hope someone can help me with my problem. 
Thank you very much! I appreciate your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int magic[n+1][n+1];
     if(argc == 2) 
        {
         for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
         {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            {
              magic[i][j] = 0;
            }
          }

          int i =0 ;//row
          int j= n / 2; //column

          for ( int k = 1; k <= n*n; k++ )
          {
             magic[j][i] = k;

             if(magic[j][i] == 0) //if the spot is empty
             {
                 if (j == 0 && i == 0)
                 {
                     j--;//go up one level
                     i--; //go left
                 }

                 else
                 {
                     if(j == 0) //if it's on the first row
                        j = n - 1;
                     else
                        j--;

                     if (i == 0) //if it's on the left column
                         i = n - 1;
                     else
                         i--;
                  }
              }

              else //if the spot is not empty
              {
                  j = j + 2;
                  i++;
              }
      }
  }


    for(int x=0; x<n; x++)
          {
             for(int y=0; y<n; y++)
                 printf("%3d", magic[x][y]);
             printf("\n");
          }

          return 0;
    }
```

Comment: decide which language are you using. You can't use both C and C++ at the same time, these are different languages. Also - what did your debugger tell you?

Comment: put your declaration of `magic[n+1][n+1]` after assigning a new value to `n` because you are creating the array when `n` is 0

Comment: what should the program do ? Just by eyeballing i see that you initialized the matrix with the dimensions 1 1

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code.

Comment: Debugger..................

Comment: Should you input the matrix or should it be generated by itself ?

Comment: The matrix should be generated by itself, we just input an odd integer n to define the size of the matrix(n*n).

Comment: what are the properties of this magic square ?

Comment: OP please have a look http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/magic-square/

Comment: Post code as text, not links or images!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use variables to declare the size of an array

```
 int magic[n+1][n+1];
```

You can:

1) Look up how to **dynamically allocate arrays**, or

2) Use a **vector**

Also, I don't think this is causing a problem now but

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

does not check to make sure that argv[1] contains numerical characters which may cause problems for you later.

Comment: `int magic[n+1][n+1]` is called *variable length array*. The problem is that it is dimension 1 by 1.

Comment: you can't do that in C++. In C it's perfectly legal syntax. Look how OP changed tags

Comment: @ Weather Vane - I don't think they are using C99

Comment: @ Fureeish - Ok wait, the question stated that you were using C++ when I wrote it

Comment: it's not me, but I know what you meant. Just delete the answer since proposing **vector** as solution makes no sense when we are dealing with C

Comment: You are right, I did not notice the (deleted) C++ tag and the code does not look like C++ anyway.

Comment: @Fureeish - Yeah, I jumped the gun here - I'm taking a closer look now there must be a logic error somewhere. Also you said earlier that there was a seg fault - is that no longer a problem?

Comment: Seg fault is not a problem anymore, but now it's generating a bunch of 0s, and the screenshot is posted. Thanks.